# Azure DevOps problem to do a git diff in bash script

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines

When I try to do a git diff (in a bash script in pipeline) 
using `git show` or `git diff HEAD HEAD^` I always get a error:

`warning: unable to access '/home/vsts/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied`

When I try to use a `@~..@` or `HEAD~` I get error similar to this one:

`fatal: ambiguous argument '@~..@'`

Does someone have the solution for this?